# Declaring array variables

Tags: java

Hey guys, got a problem with a question.

Question : Write a declaration for a variable people that could be used to refer to an Array of objects of type Person

My answer:

```
public people[];
people = new Person [100];
```

But I am getting an error saying it is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

PS. I also tried `public people[] = new Person [100]`

The error that I am receiving is this:

```
Main.java:5: <identifier> expected
public people[];
               ^

Main.java:6: <identifier> expected
people = new Person [100];
       ^

2 errors
```

The output should have been: If it wasn't correct it won't have compiled

This is what was actually produced: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public Person[] people = new Person[100];
```

- `public` is an [access modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Access_modifiers);
- `Person[]` is an array of type `Person`;
- `people` is the name of the variable that holds a *reference* to the aforementioned array;
- `new Person[100]` allocates a new array of type `Person` that is capable of storing up to 100 `Person`s.

Answer (score 2):

All java variable must have their type specified.

```
Person[] people = new Person [100];
```

You can specify qualifier to the variable. Such as:

```
final Person[] people = new Person [100]; //applies to fields and variables
private Person[] people = new Person [100];  //applies to fields only
private static volatile Person[] people = new Person [100]; //applies to fields only
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence should be:

```
Person people[];
people = new Person[100];
```

.OR.

```
Person people[] = new Person[100];
```

since your people variable is of the type Person, you should declare it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The actual declaration must declare the **name** of the variable, and its **type**.

```
Person[] people;
```

(The variable is named "people", and its type is "array of Person objects".  Make sure you have `Person` defined somewhere!)

The array creation (not declaration) actually creates an array of a given size:

```
people = new Person[100];
```

I think you may have been thrown off by the repetitive nature of the combined expression:

```
Person[] people = new Person[100];
```

... where you're specifying the type twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person [] people;
people = new Person[100];
```

Your code is almost correct (you just forgot to provide the type of the array, as shown above), but be sure you also defined a class called Person. You can add a new class to your project and just leave it empty (which is enough to compile your test code).

```
public class Person {

}
```