# Initialising Array Variables

Tags: java

I got a problem with a question.

Question: an Array instance variable called `people` has been set up by the line:

```
public Person[] people;
```

Write the line that will initialise/instantiate it to take 100 objects of type Person.

My answer:

```
    public Person[] people;

    double []people = new Person [100];`
```

The error that I am getting is this:

```
    Main.java:8: illegal start of expression

    public Person[] people;
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986925 ?

Comment: no its a different question but similar

Answer (score 3):

public is keyword for definition method or attribute visibility in a class. If you are using only variable then it is without this keyword. So it should be `Person[] people;`.

Also I think you have a mistake in `double []people = new Person [100];` It should be `people = new Person [100];` but this is not initialization of 100 objects but only 1 array of 100 references to 100 NULLs. You have to use a for cycle to call 100x `people[i] = new People();`

Answer (score 1):

This should be outside of your `main` method, within the `class`:

```
public Person[] people;
```

You can then initialize it without redeclaration:

```
people = new Person[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is written in `main`, the `public` is unecessary, so your code can be simplified to:

```
Person[] people;
people = new Person[100];
```